# Code to detect if user pressed home / tab on flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any code to detect if user pressed home / tab ?
i want make my music pause when it pressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To track lifecycle events by adding an observer to `WidgetsBinding` and then pause the music when the app pauses. 
You can take look at [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/services/lifecycle.dart) example. For all the lifecycle states look into [`AppLifecycleState`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html).

Hope that helped!