# Automatically close a Flutter modal bottom sheet when the app is paused

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bottom-sheet, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I'm using `showModalBottomSheet` to show a modal material design bottom sheet.

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
  ...
```

I'd like this bottom sheet to automatically close (pop?) when Flutter Android app is paused (for example the user is tapping the home button).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check WidgetsBindingObserver:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html. You can extend it in your modal widget and call pop() when the app state is paused.

Answer (score 0):

[Code to detect if user pressed home / tab on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729312/code-to-detect-if-user-pressed-home-tab-on-flutter) might be a viable solution?

If you detect a pause change in the app lifecycle you can probably then make a `navigator.of(context).pop` ?